# Android second screen audio synchronization

Tags: android, mpeg2-ts

For the Dutch movie "App" (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2536436), a second screen app was developed. This app synchronizes with the audio of the movie to give extra details about some scenes and some other movie fragments from other angles. It seems like it is synchronized with the audio of the movie.

For a school project, a similar app has to be developed, so we want to achieve the same result. Does anybody know of any way to synchronize app content with an external audio source? We know we have to account for environmental audio to be filtered out, but have no idea where to start. It seems that MPEG2-TS has some kind of time coding via a protocol called SMPTE, but we don't know how to "listen" to this time coding in our android app.

Does anybody have any idea? Any external libraries to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's an article](http://www.monterosa.co.uk/blog/audio-synchronization-acr-for-second-screen-apps) briefly explaining some Automated Content Recognition (ACR) techniques:

> Second screen apps use the microphone on your phone or tablet to listen to the TV and identify the channel, show or ad you are watching, and the precise location within it, based on one of two techniques:
>
> **Watermarking**
>
> Audio watermarking requires a series of inaudible “watermarks” to be encoded into the broadcast TV signal, normally using a hardware encoder in the playout suite or OB truck. Watermarks can be repeated regularly throughout the broadcast, providing a timecode, or used to trigger specific events such as questions or voting windows. The second screen app uses the device’s microphone to listen for each watermark, and decode the “payload” which uniquely identifies the channel and timecode or event.
>
> **Fingerprinting**
>
> Audio fingerprinting does not require the broadcast content to be modified. Instead, the TV content is analyzed before it is broadcast (or sometimes while it is being broadcast) and broken up into a sequence of “fingerprints” which are as unique as their name suggests. The second screen app uses an API to record a short segment of audio, and generates its own fingerprint, which is then compared to the “target” set of fingerprints, and if a match is found, the channel, show and timecode are identified.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response. We used watermarking techniques for solving this issue; we added in high-frequency audio watermarks which were detected by the smartphone using FFT analysis of the heard audio. When we detected the TV show that was being watched, we fetched the information of the show over the internet.